# Write to different file instead of overwriting file

Tags: java

I am wondering if there is an option in java to read file from specific path i.e `C:\test1.txt` change the content of the file in the memory and copy it to `D:\test2.txt` while the content of `C:\test1.txt` will not change but the affected file will be  `D:\test2.txt`

Thanks

Comment: Write to `test2.txt`.

Comment: @Tichodroma : exactly.

Comment: That mean i need to make it on the fly.

Comment: No, just write to a different `File`.

Comment: Read test1.txt into a buffer (RAM) and change some data. After that put it out into a new file.

Comment: @BlueLabel What do yo mean by `copy action` !? if you read the entire file into memory then you already have a copy, just edit what you have in memory as you want and write to `test2.txt`, that's all.

Comment: thanks i just have mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a basic solution, you can read in chunks from one `FileInputStream` and write to a `FileOutputStream`:

```
import java.io.*;
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] _) throws Exception{
    FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("test1.txt");
    FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("test2.txt");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
    int count;

    while (-1 != (count = inFile.read(buffer))) {
      // Dumb example
      for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        buffer[i] = (byte) Character.toUpperCase(buffer[i]);
      }
      outFile.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
  }
}
```

If you explicitly want the entire file in memory, you can also wrap your input in a `DataInputStream` and use [readFully(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5b%5d%29) after using `File.length()` to figure out the size of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the easiest you can do, is to use [Scanner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read file and then write with writer.

[Here are some nice examples](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42) for different java versions.

Or, you can also use [apache commons lib](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) to read/write/copy file.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        //absolute path for source file to be copied
        String source = "C:/sample.txt";
        //directory where file will be copied
        String target ="C:/Test/";

        //name of source file
        File sourceFile = new File(source);
        String name = sourceFile.getName();

        File targetFile = new File(target+name);
        System.out.println("Copying file : " + sourceFile.getName() +" from Java Program");

        //copy file from one location to other
        FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, targetFile);

        System.out.println("copying of file from Java program is completed");
    }
```